# Play! Framework & Twitter Bootstrap Dropdown active

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a play framework application and I am using twitter bootstrap for the frontend.

In my navigation bar I have four options shown below.

```
      <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="@("active".when(nav == ""))"><a href="@routes.Application.index()">@Messages("playauthenticate.navigation.home")</a></li>
          <li class="@("active".when(nav == "restricted"))"><a href="@routes.Application.restricted()">@Messages("playauthenticate.navigation.restricted")</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Journey Management<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="@routes.Application.createJourney()"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i>@Messages("journeys.dropdown.option1")</a></li>
              <li><a href="@routes.Application.Todo()"><i class="icon-calendar"></i>@Messages("journeys.dropdown.option2")</a></li>
              <li><a href="@routes.Application.Todo()"><i class="icon-star"></i>@Messages("journeys.dropdown.option3")</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

            @if(!Deadbolt.viewRoleHolderPresent()) {
                <li class="@("active".when(nav == "signup"))"><a href="@routes.Application.signup()">@Messages("playauthenticate.navigation.signup")</a></li>
            }
        </ul>
      </div>
```

When I navigate to a "Home" or "Signup" page those options become **active** on the navigation bar. My problem is whenever I select an option from the dropdown bar the "Home" button remains active. I want the "Journey Management" option to be **active** but I am not sure how to do this with a dropdown menu.

So I have made the following modifications to the HTML.

```
 <li class="@("active".when(nav == "journeys")) dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Journey Management<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="@routes.Application.createJourney()"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i>@Messages("journeys.dropdown.option1")</a></li>
              <li><a href="@routes.Application.Todo()"><i class="icon-calendar"></i>@Messages("journeys.dropdown.option2")</a></li>
              <li><a href="@routes.Application.Todo()"><i class="icon-star"></i>@Messages("journeys.dropdown.option3")</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
```

When I select an option from the Journey Management dropdown, in this case the **"Create Journey"** page (it is the only page that has an action) the localhost address is `http://localhost:9000/journeys` so I am calling a method in the journeys application route. But the Home link on the navbar remains active whilst the Journey Management dropdown on the nav bar remains inactive.

[image: Screenshot describing problem]

Here is the source for the loaded page:

This is the HTML from the actual page

```
<div class="nav-collapse">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="/restricted">Restricted page</a></li>
      <li class=" dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Journey Management<b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="/journeys"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i>Create a Journey</a>       </li>
          <li><a href="/TODO"><i class="icon-calendar"></i>View all Journeys</a></li>
          <li><a href="/TODO"><i class="icon-star"></i>View saved Journeys</a></li>
        </ul>`
```

Comment: I tried replacing the line `<li class="dropdown">` with `<li class="@("active".when(nav == "journeys"))" class="dropdown">`. This did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I foolishly neglected to include the "journeys" `@main("Journey Creator", "journeys") {` argument in the .scala.html file concerned in this question. Adding this resolving the navigation issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one `class` attribute in a tag, so you must use:

```
<li class="@("active".when(nav == "journeys")) dropdown">
```

Which will give you the desired result.

Comment: Hi, this didn't actually work for me. I tried modifying the dropdown class attribute as you mentioned above but it doesn't show the "Journey Management" dropdown on the navbar as active when I am on a page that is in /journeys.

Comment: Can you add the relevant rendered HTML to your question? I think then the problem is that `nav != "journeys"`

Comment: With rendered HTML i meant the HTML source code, not a screen shot. Again, I think the problem is that `nav != "journeys"`; but for this, there's too little information in the question.

Comment: Your posted HTML confirms my suspicion: the value `nav` is empty or undefined. The problem stated in the question is resolved by my answer (if `nav` would be correctly set). I suggest you open a new question (as this is getting confused). Keep in mind that the `@()` expressions are evaluated server-side, thus you won't have access there to the CSS-Class.